# Two selects into only one in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select

I have been a long time without using SQL, and need to deliver this in a few hours, please I need to do his in only one query, but I'm really overwhelmed and this not work when I try to  do it in only one.

I can't add this to the first query `SUM(Venta.costAmount) AS Total_Region` , it seems like `SUM` is getting some ERROR and I don't know why, of course if I I remove SUM, works.

But I need the TOTAL of the field `costAmount`. Please advise.

```
SELECT 
    Donde.region, Cuando.month, Venta.salesAmount, Que.brand
FROM 
    Donde 
INNER JOIN 
    Venta ON Donde.id = Venta.storeId       
INNER JOIN 
    Cuando ON Cuando.id = Venta.dateId 
INNER JOIN 
    Que ON Que.id= Venta.productId
WHERE 
    Que.brand ='colhogar'


SELECT  
    Donde.region, SUM(Venta.costAmount) AS Total_Region
FROM 
    Donde 
INNER JOIN 
    Venta ON Donde.id = Venta.storeId       
INNER JOIN 
    Cuando ON Cuando.id = Venta.dateId 
INNER JOIN 
    Que ON Que.id = Venta.productId
GROUP BY 
    ROLLUP (Donde.region)
```

Comment: which sql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Answer.

```
SELECT Donde.region, Cuando.month, Venta.salesAmount, Que.brand
    ,D.Total_Region CostAmount
FROM Donde INNER JOIN Venta ON Donde.id = Venta.storeId     
     INNER JOIN Cuando ON Cuando.id = Venta.dateId 
      INNER JOIN Que ON Que.id= Venta.productId
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT  Donde.region, SUM(Venta.costAmount) AS Total_Region
        FROM Donde INNER JOIN Venta ON Donde.id = Venta.storeId     
             INNER JOIN Cuando ON Cuando.id = Venta.dateId 
              INNER JOIN Que ON Que.id= Venta.productId
        GROUP BY ROLLUP (Donde.region)
        )D ON D.region=Donde.region
WHERE Que.brand ='colhogar'
```

If any issues, tell me in the comments.